# Converting NSObject to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

Hello I a class of type NSObject:

```
ProductDetails *details = [[ProductDetails alloc] init];
details.name = @"Soap1";
details.color = @"Red";
details.quantity = 4;
```

I want to pass the "details" object to a dictionary.

I did,

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:details forKey:@"details"];
```

I am passing this dict to another method which performs a check on JSONSerialization:

```
if(![NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict])
```

And I am getting a crash on this check. Am I doing anything wrong here? I know that the details I am getting is a JSON object and I am assigning it to the properties in my ProductDetails class.

Please help me. I am a noob in Objective-C.

I now tried:

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:(NSData*)details options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

All I need here is an easy way to convert details to NSData.

I noticed that I have an array inside my object may be thats why all the ways I tried is throwing an exception. However since this question is becoming to big, I have started an another question thread for it where I have displayed the data I am getting inside the object - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081104/convert-nsobject-to-nsdictionary

Comment: What is the intent here? To share it with a server that needs JSON (in which case, we'll show you how to do that)? Or are you just trying to save this to some local file so you can load it later (in which case, `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` might be better)?

Comment: All of the objects in the "nest" need to be NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString, NSNumber, or NSNull.  You can't have any other object types and convert to JSON using NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: I posted the answer for swift user with the help of @thatzprem answer. I face the challenge so I wrote the Anser

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *details = {@"name":product.name,@"color":product.color,@"quantity":@(product.quantity)};

NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:details 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Second part's source: [Generate JSON string from NSDictionary in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368867/generate-json-string-from-nsdictionary)

Comment: Thanks mmackh!! Nothing helped me may be since I have an array inside my object data. I have posted the question again with the exact data I am getting back in the object - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081104/convert-nsobject-to-nsdictionary

Comment: Please delete your other question and reformulate the current one.

Answer (score 19):

This may well be the easiest way to achieve it. Do import `#import <objc/runtime.h>` in your class file.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

ProductDetails *details = [[ProductDetails alloc] init];
details.name = @"Soap1";
details.color = @"Red";
details.quantity = 4;
NSDictionary *dict = [self dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject: details];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);

//Add this utility method in your class.
- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject:(id)obj
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([obj class], &count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
        [dict setObject:[obj valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }

    free(properties);

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
}
```

Comment: This is dangerous metaprogramming.   It assumes that the only thing that should be encoded is the various `@property` declared data and it also assumes that there will never be any other `@property` -- including ones in the superclass or added via a category -- that is intended to hold non-encodeable data.   While this works, it'll be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Works as intended. A good solution for creating a dictionary from list of properties on an object.

Comment: worth checking if `[obj valueForKey:key]` is not nil before trying to add to dictionary, otherwise you risk your app crashing in the event theres no value

Answer (score 3):

As mmackh said, you want to define a custom method for your `ProductDetails` object that will return a simple `NSDictionary` of values, e.g.:

```
@implementation ProductDetails

- (id)jsonObject
{
    return @{@"name"     : self.name,
             @"color"    : self.color,
             @"quantity" : @(self.quantity)};
}

...
```

Let's assume that we added `manufacturer` property to our `ProductDetails`, which referenced a `ManufacturerDetails` class. We'd just write a `jsonObject` for that class, too:

```
@implementation ManufacturerDetails

- (id)jsonObject
{
    return @{@"name"     : self.name,
             @"address1" : self.address1,
             @"address2" : self.address2,
             @"city"     : self.city,
             ...
             @"phone"    : self.phone};
}

...
```

And then change the `jsonObject` for `ProductDetails` to employ that, e.g.:

```
@implementation ProductDetails

- (id)jsonObject
{
    return @{@"name"         : self.name,
             @"color"        : self.color,
             @"quantity"     : @(self.quantity),
             @"manufacturer" : [self.manufacturer jsonObject]};
}

...
```

If you have potentially nested collection objects (arrays and/or dictionaries) with custom objects that you want to encode, you could write a `jsonObject` method for each of those, too:

```
@interface NSDictionary (JsonObject)

- (id)jsonObject;

@end

@implementation NSDictionary (JsonObject)

- (id)jsonObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [self enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(jsonObject)])
            [dictionary setObject:[obj jsonObject] forKey:key];
        else
            [dictionary setObject:obj forKey:key];
    }];

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionary];
}

@end

@interface NSArray (JsonObject)

- (id)jsonObject;

@end

@implementation NSArray (JsonObject)

- (id)jsonObject
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(jsonObject)])
            [array addObject:[obj jsonObject]];
        else
            [array addObject:obj];
    }];

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}

@end
```

If you do something like that, you can now convert arrays or dictionaries of your custom objects object into something that can be used for generating JSON:

```
NSArray *products = @[[[Product alloc] initWithName:@"Prius"  color:@"Green" quantity:3],
                      [[Product alloc] initWithName:@"Accord" color:@"Black" quantity:1],
                      [[Product alloc] initWithName:@"Civic"  color:@"Blue"  quantity:2]];

id productsJsonObject = [products jsonObject];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:productsJsonObject options:0 error:&error];
```

If you're simply trying to save these objects in a file, I'd suggest `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. But if you need to generate JSON objects for your own private classes, you can do something like the above might work.

Answer (score 3):

In .h File

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ContactDetail : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *fullName;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *mobileNumbers;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *Emails;
@property (assign) bool Isopen;
@property (assign) bool IsChecked;
-(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end
```

in .m file

```
#import "ContactDetail.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation ContactDetail

@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;
@synthesize fullName;
@synthesize mobileNumbers;
@synthesize Emails;

@synthesize IsChecked,Isopen;

//-(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
//    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.fullName,@"fullname",self.mobileNumbers,@"mobileNumbers",self.Emails,@"emails", nil];
//}

- (NSDictionary *)dictionary {
    unsigned int count = 0;
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
        id value = [self valueForKey:key];

        if (value == nil) {
            // nothing todo
        }
        else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]
                 || [value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
                 || [value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] || [value isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {
            // TODO: extend to other types
            [dictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
        }
        else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]]) {
            [dictionary setObject:[value dictionary] forKey:key];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Invalid type for %@ (%@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), key);
        }
    }
    free(properties);
    return dictionary;
}
@end
```

if any crash ,You check the property (NSMutableArray,NSString,etc ) in **else if** condition inside of **for**.

In Your Controller, in any func...

```
-(void)addItemViewController:(ConatctViewController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSMutableArray *)SelectedContact
{
    NSLog(@"%@",SelectedContact);

    NSMutableArray *myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (ContactDetail *cont in SelectedContact) {
        [myData addObject:[cont dictionary]];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    if ([jsonData length] > 0 &&
        error == nil){
//        NSLog(@"Successfully serialized the dictionary into data = %@", jsonData);
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"JSON String = %@", jsonString);
    }
    else if ([jsonData length] == 0 &&
             error == nil){
        NSLog(@"No data was returned after serialization.");
    }
    else if (error != nil){
        NSLog(@"An error happened = %@", error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject:(id)obj {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([obj class], &count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
        [dict setObject:[obj valueForKey:key] ? [obj valueForKey:key] : @"" forKey:key];
    }

    free(properties);

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The perfect way to do this is by using a library for serialization/deserialization 
many libraries are available but one i like is 
JagPropertyConverter
https://github.com/jagill/JAGPropertyConverter

it can convert your Custom object into NSDictionary and vice versa
even it support to convert dictionary or array or any custom object within your object (i.e Composition)

```
JAGPropertyConverter *converter = [[JAGPropertyConverter alloc]init];
converter.classesToConvert = [NSSet setWithObjects:[ProductDetails class], nil];


//For Object to Dictionary 
NSDictionary *dictDetail = [converter convertToDictionary:detail];
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dictDetail options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert object (say modelObject) to dictionary at runtime with the help of **objc/runtime.h** class but that has certain limitations and is **not recommended**.

Considering **MVC**, mapping logic should be implemented in Model class.

```
@interface ModelObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString *p1;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *p2;
-(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end


#import "ModelObject.h"

@implementation ModelObject
-(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [dict setValue:self.p1 forKey:@"p1"];// you can give different key name here if you want 
    [dict setValue:self.p2 forKey:@"p2" ];

    return dict;
}
@end
```

Uses:

```
NSDictionary *modelObjDict = [modelObj dictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
NSDictionary *dict = [details valuesForAttributes:@[@"name", @"color"]];
```

And compare what the dictionary contains. Then try to convert it to JSON. And look at the JSON spec - what data types can go into a JSON encoded file?

Comment: Thanks Wain!! Nothing helped me here... May be because the data I am getting inside an object has an array too. I have posted the question again - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081104/convert-nsobject-to-nsdictionary

Comment: I know, you shouldn't repost. Show all of your custom classes and the properties they have and what your desired JSON output is. Delete one of your 2 questions and update the other with all of the appropriate information.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the `NSObject+APObjectMapping` category which is available on GitHub: https://github.com/aperechnev/APObjectMapping

It's a quit easy. Just describe the mapping rules in your class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSObject+APObjectMapping.h"

@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * someNumber;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * someString;
@end

@implementation MyCustomClass
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)objectMapping {
  NSMutableDictionary * mapping = [super objectMapping];
  if (mapping) {
    NSDictionary * objectMapping = @{ @"someNumber": @"some_number",
                                      @"someString": @"some_string" };
  }
  return mapping
}
@end
```

And then you can easily map your object to dictionary:

```
MyCustomClass * myObj = [[MyCustomClass alloc] init];
myObj.someNumber = @1;
myObj.someString = @"some string";
NSDictionary * myDict = [myObj mapToDictionary];
```

Also you can parse your object from dictionary:

```
NSDictionary * myDict = @{ @"some_number": @123,
                           @"some_string": @"some string" };
MyCustomClass * myObj = [[MyCustomClass alloc] initWithDictionary:myDict];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

Now the swift is very popular and most of the SDK's are written in Objective C, we need to convert `NSObject to NSDictionary`, With the Help of @thatzprem Answer, I wrote an **extension for Swift** which will convert our `NSObject` into `NSDictionary`, then we can use that NSDictionary to simple Dictionary or JSON Object or other purpose. I hope so this will help out the Swift User.

```
extension NSObject {
func convertNSObjectToNSDictionary() -> [AnyHashable : Any]? {
        var dict: [AnyHashable : Any] = [:]

        var count: UInt32 = 0
        let properties = class_copyPropertyList(type(of: self), UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(mutating: &count)) //as? objc_property_t

        for i in 0..<Int(count) {
            var key: String? = nil
            if let property = properties?[i] as? objc_property_t {
                key = String(utf8String: property_getName(property))
            }
            //dict[key] = (obj as? NSObject)?.value(forKey: key ?? "")
            dict[key] = (self).value(forKey: key ?? "")
        }

        free(properties)

        return dict
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boy, what a mess!!! from the hilarious digging into ObjC runtime to create a general-purpose serializer for any object hierarchy, to the cumbersome setting one-by-one dictionary entries -- have everyone forgot KVC?

Here's the documentation from `NSKeyValueCoding.h`:

```
/* Given an array of keys, return a dictionary containing the keyed attribute values, to-one-related objects, and/or collections of to-many-related objects. Entries for which -valueForKey: returns nil have NSNull as their value in the returned dictionary.
*/
- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:(NSArray<NSString *> *)keys;
```

and the line of code to use in the OP's specific question:

```
ProductDetails *details = [[ProductDetails alloc] init];
details.name = @"Soap1";
details.color = @"Red";
details.quantity = 4;
```

is:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [details dictionaryWithValuesForKeys: @[@"name", @"color", @"quantity"] ];
```

Two notes:

- The reason to specify the keys - is that for a custom class you would
  frequently have "private properties" you do NOT want to serialize
  into your JSON, so here you can select which ones go out.
- All basic Cocoa collections (NSArray, NSSet, NSDictionary) can't
  contain nil values (or keys for that matter) so if `details.name` is
  `nil` - attempt to set it as a dictionary value would crash. The
  solution: the method automatically places an `NSNull` instance
  (`[NSNull null]`) as the value, and you ALWAYS get the keys you want.
  BTW - JSON accepts "NULL" values and `NSJSONSerialization` will correctly convert these NSNulls into JSON's NULL representation.

I think this is the preferred solution to the OP's specific scenario.