# Remove keys/values from nsdictionary

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to convert my coredata to json, I have been struggling to get this to work but have found a way that is almost working.

my code:

```
NSArray *keys = [[[self.form entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
        NSDictionary *dict = [self.form dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
        NSLog(@"dict::%@",dict);

        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                           options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                             error:&error];

        if (! jsonData) {
            NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"json::%@",jsonString);
        }
```

also "form" is:

```
 @property (strong, retain) NSManagedObject *form;
```

This works fine except I have NSIndexSet saved in some of the coredata attributes. This poses a problem with the JSON write. Now, my indexsets do not need to be converted to json so I was wondering if there was a way to delete all indexes from the dict? or maybe there is a better way to do this I am unaware of.

here is part of the nslog of dict:

```
...
    whereExtent = "";
    wiring =     (
    );
    wiring1 = "<NSIndexSet: 0x82b0600>(no indexes)";
    wiringUpdated = "<null>";
    yardFenceTrees = "<null>";
}
```

so in this case I want to remove "wiring1" from dict but need to be able to do it in a "dynamic" way (not using the name "wiring1" to remove it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obj-C easy method to convert from NSObject with properties to NSDictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318366/obj-c-easy-method-to-convert-from-nsobject-with-properties-to-nsdictionary)

Comment: @Abizern All I want to do is remove nsindexset (key and value) from my dict, How is this a duplicate of that question?

Comment: Do you have array, set or dictionary properties as part of this object, or is it just a straight list of properties?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To be able to delete values, your dictionary must be an instance of `NSMutableDictionary` class.

For dynamically removing values, get all keys from dict, test the object of each key and remove unnecessary objects:

```
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
for (int i = 0 ; i < [keys count]; i++)
 {
   if ([dict[keys[i]] isKindOfClass:[NSIndexSet class]])
   {
     [dict removeObjectForKey:keys[i]];
   }
}
```

Note: Removing values does not work with fast enumeration. As an alternative fast hack, you may create a new dictionary without unnecessary objects.

Comment: This is almost perfect but I think I need to be checking the value of the key for each key because when I check the key its just (class) _PFEncodeString

Answer (score 8):

Use NSMutableDictionary instead NSDictionary.Your code will looks like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[self.form dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys] mutableCopy]; //create dict
[dict removeObjectForKey:@"wiring1"]; //remove object
```

Don't forget use mutableCopy.

Answer (score 1):

This sample code will pass through an `NSDictionary` and build a new `NSMutableDictionary` containing only JSON-safe properties.

At the moment it does not work recursively, e.g. if your dictionary contains a dictionary or array, it will drop it rather than pass through the dictionary itself and fix that, but that is simple enough to add.

```
// Note: does not work recursively, e.g. if the dictionary contains an array or dictionary it will be dropped.
NSArray *allowableClasses = @[[NSString class], [NSNumber class], [NSDate class], [NSNull class]];
NSDictionary *properties = @{@"a":@"hello",@"B":[[NSIndexSet alloc] init]};
NSMutableDictionary *safeProperties = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[properties enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    BOOL allowable = NO;
    for (Class allowableClass in allowableClasses)          {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:allowableClass])
        {
            allowable = YES;
            break;
        }
    }       
    if (allowable)
    {
        safeProperties[key] = obj;
    }
}];
NSLog(@"unsafe: %@, safe: %@",properties,safeProperties);
```