# convert NSObject to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, nsdictionary

How do i to convert NSObject to NSDictionary?

At first step i have converted NSDictionary to NSObject like,

```
QRCodeData *obj = [[QRCodeData alloc] initWithQRcodeData:myDictonary];
```

**QRCodeData.h**

```
@interface QRCodeData : NSObject
-(instancetype)initWithQRcodeData:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;
@end
```

`QRCodeData.m`

```
@implementation QRCodeData

-(instancetype)initWithQRcodeData:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){

        self.name = dictionary[@"userName"];
        self.phoneNumber = dictionary[@"mobileNo"];

    }
    return self;

}
@end
```

I want my Dictionary from object, it is possible to get?

***Please help and thanks in advance..***

Comment: Specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10318659/299924) which assumes you use the same names for the properties of your object and the keys of your dictionary, which sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: you want Dictionary  in same class or in other class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply get dictionary like,

```
  NSDictionary *dict = @{@"userName": obj.name ,@"mobileNo" : obj.phoneNumber };
```

here `obj` is `QRCodeData`'s object.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: What do i write in QRCodeData class?

Comment: you not need to write anything in your `QRCodeData` class. you should have property in .h file like `name` and `phoneNumber` and when you want to convert it in dictionary in any class just import `QRCodeData.h` and make object of it and by that object you can make dictionary as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to add this method in the `QRCodeData` class.

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue
{
  return @{@"userName" : self.name, @"mobileNo" : self.phoneNumber};
}
```

If `userName` and `phoneNumber` could be `nil` you have to check that.

To call with

```
NSDictionary *dict = [obj dictionaryValue];
```

Comment: Try these two lines `QRCodeData *codeData = [[QRCodeData alloc] initWithQRcodeData:@{@"userName" : @"John Doe", @"mobileNo" : @"1-234-5678"}];`  `NSLog(@"%@", [codeData dictionaryValue]);` You should get the same dictionary as passed in the initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Key-Value Coding(KVC) for this purpose. First, provide class method for all keys you want to share:

```
+ (NSSet *)keysToCopy
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"userName", @"mobileNio", .....];
}
```

Then you can do something like in your init method:

```
for (key in [[self class] keysToCopy])
{
    [self setValue:dictionary[key] forKey:key];
}
```

and provide another method to revert it back to `NSDictionary`:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryRepresentation
{
    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (key in [[self class] keysToCopy])
    {
        [result setObject:[self valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
}
```

The only problem remains that not every property is compatible to `NSDictionary` storing.

This approach allows you to scale this solution to any Cocoa object and it doesn't require you to change anything but `keysToCopy` method in case if there are new properties to share.